# REDES LAN y WAN bloquear router

Tags: redes, internet-explorer, router

Estoy empezando con redes.
Tengo una duda como podría crear o como seria para hacer una LAN que tenga bloqueado el acceso al router (192.168.1.1) pero que si tenga Internet.

Gracias!

Comment: define "bloqueado el acceso al router", si no accede al router no puede encontrar la ruta (route) hacia y desde internet

Comment: Que en esa red no se pueda acceder a la IP del router en este caso 192.168.1.1

Comment: Estás queriendo bloquear el acceso a la administración del router? es decir, bloquear el acceso a la web/telnet/ssh del router?
Si ese es el caso, podría crearse una regla de firewall para restringir el acceso a dichos puertos, pero depende un poco del modelo del router.
Contanos un poco más de tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Es imposible se el router es el gateway por defecto para conectarse a internet.

Si crea otra red, al final, debería tener acceso al gateway.

Aun creando dos redes, si el gateway es el mismo tendrán acceso.

Otra cosa, es bloquear el acceso a ciertos servicios del router a una red o a determinadas IP.

Eso se hace con el firewall que tenga el router.

Answer (score 0):

Hola buen  dia si pudieras detallar un poco mas el caso por que esa ip que colocas es de una puerta de enlace que y si es la de tu router de proveedor la va a necesitar en cual quier red para poder conectarte a intenet.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [answer] y [No tengo reputación para dejar un comentario, pero quiero decir algo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3765/107347)